# Best Language for cross-platform screen recording and streaming?

Tags: windows, macos, video, video-streaming, video-capture

So I'm looking to build an application that will be able to record the users screen and stream it at the same time. I would like the application to run on both Windows and OSX. I don't have a high level of programming experience in any language, just basic understanding in C, C++, JS, (funny how each class you take in college wants a different language). I'm also pretty well versed in HTML and CSS but that is kind of irrelevant for this topic.

I've been looking around and it looks like the best solution is going to be writing the core of the program in one language, and then developing the Interface side for each platform differently, using appropriate languages and bindings for the different platforms (Objective-C and Cocoa for OSX and so forth).

I'm open to all suggestions, this project doesn't have a deadline or anything, I'm really just intending it as a learning experience. I've never done anything with video capture and streaming before, so I'm looking for suggestions as to which road to go down language-wise for this project.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution that comes to my mind is to use [VLC](http://vwww.ideolan.org).
this is obviously not a "language" but an application, but it supports screen-capture and streaming on all of your target platforms (and more).

if this is not an option (e.g. because you don't want a separate application), you could use VLC's C-api for acquiring screen capture and use whatever you like for streaming.

if you want to only rely on native functionality, i would use C/C++ for the application and write the OSX part in ObjC/ObjC++ and Cocoa.